# Django STATIC_URL with full domain breaks static assets locally

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When working locally on a Django project that uses static files and the default static files backend, I am running into an issue when I want to get full absolute urls to the static files instead of only the path.

My settings:

```
DEBUG = True
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
INSTALLED_APPS = ["django.contrib.staticfiles", ...]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static_root"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media_root"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / "static",)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
```

Everything works, the admin's CSS is loaded, images work, etc. But when I get the path of a file with this code:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
static_path = staticfiles_storage.url("path_to_folder/some_file.jpg")
```

That result is a relative path: `/static/path_to_folder/some_file.jpg`. This is a problem when these urls are used from my external frontend: it now has to prepend the backend's base url to all static assets. But if I'd want to deploy the static assets to S3 for example, in production, then I should not prepend these paths with the domain of the backend.

So what I tried to do was to change the `STATIC_URL` setting to `http://localhost:8000/static/`. That way the full url is passed to the frontend, but I could really easily change this setting in the backend in production.

And this is where the problem rears its head: when I change `STATIC_URL` to `http://localhost:8000/static/`, none of my static files work anymore, I just get a 404. The admin page also is completely unstyled because of this.

So, to make a long story short: how can I use an absolute `STATIC_URL` in local development mode with `DEBUG=True`?

I have created a reproduction repro: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/django-problem-repro.

Comment: what do you mean with "external frontend"?

Comment: A SPA website. The Django backend is the API returning JSON. Some of the models contain links to static assets, and it's these that I want to return as full absolute URLs.

Comment: "...when I change STATIC_URL to http://localhost:8000/static/, none of my static files work anymore, I just get a 404."

Can you share the URLs that are 404ing? That'll let us see what Django is building and why it's not matching the availability of the static files that runserver can deliver

Comment: For example a URL like http://localhost:8000/static/sr_app/img/products/32-lives/rect.png works perfect when STATIC_URL is set to `/static/` but breaks when the STATIC_URL is set to `http://localhost:8000/static/`.

Comment: Have you checked your console and networking panels in the browser developer tools for any errors or warnings?

Comment: It's just a 404. Not much else to see there.

Comment: Are these files actually in your STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise they wouldn't be served when STATIC_URL is set to `/static/`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve.

Simply add this to the end of urls.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views
from django.urls import re_path

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    ]
```

Then the static files will work again even with an absolute URL as the STATIC_URL setting.